# mutating column values based on multiple condtions

Tags: r

I need to mutate the values of a column in a data frame with multiple conditions.

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
              city = c("Newyork", "NewYork", "NewYrk", "newYork", "Newyork",
                  "London","Londonn","Mumbai","mumbai","Bombay")
                )
```

I need to `mutate` the city column values based on the following conditions

1. when city starts with `new` (case insensitive) then `Newyork`
2. when city starts with `Lond` then `London`
3. When city starts with `mum` or `bom` (case insensitive) then `Mumbai`

both base-r and `dplyr` based solutions would be nice.

What have I tried ?

```
df[df$city %in% c('NewYork', 'NewYrk', 'newYork' ),]$city <- "Newyork"
```

This gets the #1 done, but not exactly as in the condition - that it  starts with `new` (case insensitive)

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Sotos - updated in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a nested `ifelse` statement along with `substring`, i.e.

```
ind <- substring(tolower(df$city), 1, 3)
ifelse(ind == 'new', 'New York', ifelse(ind == 'lond', 'London', 'Mumbai'))
 #[1] "New York" "New York" "New York" "New York" "New York" "Mumbai"   "Mumbai"  
 #[8] "Mumbai"   "Mumbai"   "Mumbai"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one? not sure how to do the OR for regex for the last condition:

```
# look for 'new' then use the index to subset city and replace with Newyork
df$city[grep(pattern = "new", x = df$city, ignore.case = TRUE)] <- "Newyork"

# look for 'lond' then use the index to subset city and replace with London
df$city[grep(pattern = "Lond", x = df$city, ignore.case = TRUE)] <- "London"

# look for 'mum' then use the index to subset city and replace with Mumbai
df$city[grep(pattern = "mum", x = df$city, ignore.case = TRUE)] <- "Mumbai"

# look for 'bom' then use the index to subset city and replace with Mumbai
df$city[grep(pattern = "bom", x = df$city, ignore.case = TRUE)] <- "Mumbai"

# OR
df$city[grep(pattern = "bom|mum", x = df$city, ignore.case = TRUE)] <- "Mumbai"
```